# How can I choose between otherwise indistinguishable people in the crew roster?

Tags: return-of-the-obra-dinn

There are a few groups of people in the crew list who are in the same part of the crew (e.g. Seaman or Midshipman) and have the same nationality (so hearing them speak doesn't narrow it down more), and are never mentioned by name in any memory. What other kinds of information is available that allows me to associate one of those names with a particular crew member?

Comment: Any specific people you had in mind? A screenshot could help

Comment: I'm looking for an guidance about how to approach this problem, not the solution for specific people. But one example of what I'm talking about is the 4 (I think) Indian Seamen. One is mentioned by name in a memory, but the other 3 are not.

Answer (score 2):

One way to tell crewmembers apart is by their hammocks. You can examine details such as the numbers on their hammocks, what items are stored nearby, and what clothing they wear.

Comment: This; the hammocks turn out to be of vital importance. You can also deduce some characters by whether the hammocks are still up at various points in the story (once a character has died, the hammock is packed away, unless no one is left alive to do so - see the lone hammock left on the ship in the present day!).

Comment: An additional related quirk, while some sailors will be nearly entirely covered up while they sleep their feet necessarily dangle out of their cots, said sailors probably only have a single pair of shoes/socks for the entire voyage ;)

Comment: I didn't even see that the hammocks were numbered until I saw this answer. That definitely helps. It only seems to help with part of the roster, though. If I understand right, the officers and passengers have beds instead of hammocks, and I haven't seen any numbers on those.